# Unable to close loop when variable is not present in file being read

Tags: python, list, file, loops

I have to create a program in Python that reads a text file of the top 200 boy or girl names and display whether a user-inputted name is among those or not. If it is, I have to say what the ranking is.

If I put in a valid name, everything's perfect, but I'm having trouble with when I want to put in a name that isn't a popular name.

Relevant code:

```
def searchgirls(searchGirlName):
    for girlsearchresult in searchGirlName:
        GirlNames = open("GirlNames.txt", "r")
        nameLine = GirlNames.readline()
        lineNumber = 0
        NumberOfLines = 0
        while nameLine != searchGirlName and nameLine<201:
            lineNumber += 1
            if searchGirlName in nameLine:
                characterPos = int(nameLine.find(searchGirlName))
                print(searchGirlName, " is the #", lineNumber, "most popular girl name.")
            nameLine = GirlNames.readline()
        if nameLine==201:
            print(searchGirlName, " is not among the most popular girl names.")
        GirlNames.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of str and int
```

The thing is though, without the "< 201" part, I can't leave the loop if a name's not in the text file.

Comment: You've confused `nameLine` and `lineNumber`.  `nameLine` is a string.  You want `lineNumber < 201`

Comment: You may want to change your main loop to `for nameLine in GirlNames:`. It will be much easier to reason about than a `while` loop with `readline()` calls. And you can then limit it to the first 200 by just changing the loop to `for nameLine in itertools.islice(GirlNames, 200):`. If you actually need the numbers as well, you can wrap that it in `for n, name in enumerate(…, 1):`. By putting each of these things into a single function call instead of scattered across multiple lines of your code, there's much less opportunity to get things wrong.

Comment: As a side note, why are you doing `int(nameLine.find(searchGirlName))`? First, `find` already returns an `int`, so whatever you were trying to do there presumably isn't happening. Second, you aren't even using `characterPos`, so why bother calculating it?

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/d1ed16846b6dcf280ac28cf679970177) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant `lineNumber < 201`.

You actually don't need this to tell if you get to the end of the file.